# Generic view generator unable to infer type swift

Tags: swift, generics

have some struggle get my generic view generator working.

the idea behind is to have a array of different concrete view settings.
to generate the resulting views ive made the function in the pastebin below.

but it cannot infer the right type for the cell. 
can anybody gibe me a hint ?

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// Protocols
protocol SettingType {
    var color: UIColor { get }
}
protocol CellType {
    func configure(with setting: SettingType)
}

//  Concrete Settings
final class Concrete1Setting: SettingType {
    var color: UIColor = .blue
}

final class Concrete2Setting: SettingType {
    var color: UIColor = .green
}

//  Concrete Cells
final class Concrete1Cell: UIView, CellType {
    func configure(with setting: SettingType) {
        print("Configured Cell 1")
        self.backgroundColor = setting.color
    }
}

final class Concrete2Cell: UIView, CellType {
    func configure(with setting: SettingType) {
        print("Configured Cell 2")
        self.backgroundColor = setting.color
    }
}

//  Generic generator
func makeConcreteCell<S: SettingType, T: CellType>(_ setting: S) -> T {
    switch setting {
    case is Concrete1Setting:
        return Concrete1Cell() as! T
    case is Concrete2Setting:
        return Concrete2Cell() as! T
    default: fatalError()
    }
}

// Test
var cells: [CellType] = [Concrete1Cell(), Concrete2Cell()]
let settings: [SettingType] = [Concrete1Setting(), Concrete2Setting()]
for setting in settings {
    cells.append(makeConcreteCell(setting))         // CompileError: Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred
}
// expect array equal to [Concrete1Cell, Concrete2Cell]
```

Comment: @vacawama sorry, but this don’t worked at first try. Updated my post

Comment: It's because, when you store those two setting in a [SettingType] array, it lose the concrete type information, therefore, when you pass it to a generic function, it can't cast the type correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the generic function for `makeConcreteCell`.  Just have it take and return the prototypes:

```
func makeConcreteCell(_ setting: SettingType) -> CellType {
    switch setting {
    case is Concrete1Setting:
        return Concrete1Cell()
    case is Concrete2Setting:
        return Concrete2Cell()
    default: fatalError()
    }
}
```

Generics are used when you want the compiler to write a specific function for each specific type.  That isn't what you need here.  The one function works.

---

You want to use the `CellType`s as `UIView`s.

Create a base class called `CellTypeClass` that is a `UIView` and adopts the `CellType` protocol:

```
// Protocols
protocol SettingType {
    var color: UIColor { get }
}
protocol CellType {
    func configure(with setting: SettingType)
}

//  Concrete Settings
final class Concrete1Setting: SettingType {
    var color: UIColor = .blue
}

final class Concrete2Setting: SettingType {
    var color: UIColor = .green
}

class CellTypeClass: UIView, CellType {
    func configure(with setting: SettingType) {
        fatalError("You must override this function")
    }
}

//  Concrete Cells
final class Concrete1Cell: CellTypeClass {
    override func configure(with setting: SettingType) {
        print("Configured Cell 1")
        self.backgroundColor = setting.color
    }
}

final class Concrete2Cell: CellTypeClass {
    override func configure(with setting: SettingType) {
        print("Configured Cell 2")
        self.backgroundColor = setting.color
    }
}

//  Generic generator
func makeConcreteCell(_ setting: SettingType) -> CellTypeClass {
    switch setting {
    case is Concrete1Setting:
        return Concrete1Cell()
    case is Concrete2Setting:
        return Concrete2Cell()
    default: fatalError()
    }
}

// Test
var cells: [CellTypeClass] = [Concrete1Cell(), Concrete2Cell()]
let settings: [SettingType] = [Concrete1Setting(), Concrete2Setting()]
for setting in settings {
    cells.append(makeConcreteCell(setting))
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if I do so i have an array of CellTypes. CellTypes are no UIViews so I cannot add it as a subview. So I thought generating concrete subclasses. So I have to force the result to UIView again ?  Can I constraint the protocol „CellType" to UIView to be sure that CellTypes are some kind of UIView ?

Comment: I don't know if you can do that.  How about just having `makeConcreteCell` return `UIView`?